# Support for mappingResources in JPA autoconfiguration

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

In my project I need to set some specific JPA mappings by using several orm-xxx.xml files.

Currently I cannot use JPA autoconfiguration of spring boot because there is no predefined property to set 'mappingResources' like spring.jpa.xxx or any such attribute in @EntityScan like e.g. 'basePackages'. 
Only because of this now I need to specify whole entity manager bean on my own!?

Is there another way to set this for autoconfiguration or why is there no support for this in JPA autoconfig?

Comment: Because you ideally should use annotations and not xml. If you want to add things to the bean simply add a `BeanPostProcessor` and operate only on beans of type `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and set the property if you really must, but I would recommend using annotations instead of xml.

Comment: In general we use annotations. Reason for using the xml was that we wanted to separate physical db information (like explicit column mappings) from general abstracted jpa layer in the code for the annotations. I was only wondering why 'mappingResources' seems to be the only setting of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean that is not usable with JPA autoconfig.